# Does decreasing image size increase the frame rate for continuous shooting on a DSLR?

Tags: canon, burst-mode, canon-1100d

If shooting in RAW mode decreases the burst rate to 2 frames per second (on Canon 1100D), then would using a lower resolution JPG setting increase the frame rate?

Please tell me if I have mis-understood the concept. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, a DSLR has a fixed maximum frame rate, and it will take images at that rate until the memory buffer is full. After that the rate drops depending on how fast the images can be converted and written to the memory card.

The Canon 1100D has two different maximum frame rates, 2 fps for RAW format and 3 fps for JPEG format:

> "Continuous: 2 fps up to 5 RAW frames / 3 fps up to 830 JPEG"

So, whatever resolution you pick, it won't go faster than 3 fps.

A lower resolution will let you take more images before the memory buffer fills up and the rate drops, so that would increase the 830, but you would not normally take that long bursts anyway...

Comment: Thanks, this is what I had (guessed and) feared to be true. So looks like I should fall back to anticipating the moment rather than relying on bursts to capture it.

Comment: Also I guess I shall perform a series of tests just to confirm the limitation. Who knows, as @Itai said below, 1100D might turn out to be an exception.

Comment: I did a bit of testing yesterday. It turns out you are right. Changing size of image does not really increase the frame capture rate. Though I was able to get 4 frames (instead of 3) at lowest resolution 720X480(I was looking at timestamps in camera, looking at the seconds part). But then the next second had only 2 frames (lol) so I lost whatever happiness those 4 frames had given me.

**Conclusion: On Canon 1100D, you get 3 FPS, and nothing more, not even half a frame.**

Answer (score 4):

The amount of data to save to the memory card is one of several factors which affect framerate. As you've noted, big RAW files can drag things down. Saving smaller files — lower resolution or higher compression — can work around this limitation.

But at some point, other limitations, like physical shutter speed, come into effect. If you've hit one of those, smaller files won't help.

Comment: Don't know about the Canon 1100D specifically, but for cameras with buffers lowering your filesize will let you shoot many more photos before it starts to "drag" because the buffer is full and you're writing to the card. Drag here meaning that ***pop-pop-pop-pop-pop-pop-pop-pop-pop.....pop.....pop.....*** that bit!

Comment: mattdm Thanks. 

I am yet to verify this, but so far, the time it takes to take one shot on 1100D is noticeably longer than other high end cameras (e.g. 7D). So looks like there is surely a physical limitation. I will test and verify.

@AndrewHeath The sound my camera shutter makes is not even close to *pop*... its more like _*trrrTchaakkk*_ :D

Answer (score 3):

**On DSLRs, 99% of times, the frame rate stays the same regardless of resolution.**

Yours is one exception but not the only one. The Pentax K20D for example shot at 20 FPS at 1 MP.

From capture to storage there are a chain of events happening and the frame rate is limited by the slowest step: AF, Metering, Exposure (Shutter), Mirror, Reading sensor, converting sensor data (JPEG only), write to buffer and write to memory card. These are more or less the steps involved.

It is most likely the 1100D has a limited throughout somewhere and cannot fill its buffer fast enough for 3 FPS of RAW data. Some other cameras quote a different speed when AF is locked at the first frame versus when it is continuously adjusted. You can guess which part does not keep up. So the camera achieves more speed by skipping the AF step. The K20D skips the shutter (using an electronic one) and the mirror (keeping the viewfinder blank during the burst) in order to reach 20 FPS.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will try to find out if my DSLR is one of those exceptions or not. :)